# How to delete columns of a range Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range named "Start" located at cell "I21". And I have another range named "End" located at cell "Q21". I want to write a code to delete all the columns between them. In other words, I want to delete columns J,K,L,M,N,O,P completely. Here is the code I have:

```
with ThisWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
    'unprotect sheet
    .Columns(.Range("Start").Column+1 & ":" & .Range("End").Column-1).Select
     Selection.Delete Shift:xlLeft
End with
```

when it comes to the first line .Columns... it gives me an error as undefined application.
please help,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Range(Range("start").Offset(,1), Range("end").Offset(,-1)).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify a row reference...

```
ActiveSheet.Range(, MyColumn).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Where `'myColumn'` is an arbitrary reference to a column number or anything you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim xlsRange As Excel.Range

    xlsRange = xlsSheet.Range("i2", "i10")

    xlsRange.EntireColumn.Delete()
```